# Force login in buddypress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, authentication, buddypress

I have problem with Buddypress. I add to menu link to user profile

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_profile_bp_link_to_nav', 10, 2 );
function add_profile_bp_link_to_nav( $items, $args ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
     $items .= '<li><a href="' . bp_loggedin_user_domain( '/' ) . '">' . __('My profile', 'buddypress' ) . '</a>    </li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
```

and then i add

```
function force_login() {
      is_user_logged_in() || auth_redirect();
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'force_login', 1 );`
```

because I want the user be redirected to the logged in wp-login.php.
And now when I click on the my acount button I'm redirected to wp-login.php. 
How to redirected users to login.php, and keep and keep correct operation of the My acount button ?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, just drop it in your child functions.php

```
// stop guests from accessing the site, forces them to join 
function bp_guest_redirect() {
global $bp;
if ( bp_is_activity_component() || bp_is_groups_component() || bp_is_blogs_component() ||     bp_is_page( BP_MEMBERS_SLUG ) ) {
// enter the slug or component conditional here
if(!is_user_logged_in()) { // not logged in user
wp_redirect( get_option('https://site.com/') . '/join/' );
} // user will be redirect to any link to want
}
}
add_filter('get_header','bp_guest_redirect',1);
```